# First form from many gets submitted on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

**Problem:** Multiple forms on the same page, but only the first one is being submitted.

**Tried the following:** 
Equating the data-ids of submit button and Form  inorder to submit the clicked form (No Luck)
Dynamic form creation using Javascript.(disbanded that idea after a few tries since it was on a deadline)

**Usecase**
The number of forms depends on the User. If there is just one comment from him, the form submits, while if there are say 4 forms, only the first one will submit.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id');
        var form_id = $(this.form).data('id');
        if (parseInt(data_id, 10) == parseInt(form_id, 10)) {
            var commentid = document.getElementByID('commentid');
            alert(commentid + formid);
        } else {
            alert("10");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
if($comment['Comment_Username'] ==$this->getUser()->getName()) 
{$output .='div class="panel" data-class="'.$comment['CommentID'].'">';
$output .='<form class="form" action="" method="post" data-  id="'.$comment['CommentID'].'">';
$output .='<textarea name="edit_text' class="box" rows="2" cols="1">'.$this->getCommentText($comment['Comment_Text']).'</textarea>';
$output .='<input name="commentid" type="hidden" id="commentid" value="'.$comment['CommentID'].'"/>';
$output .='<input type="button' data-id="'.$comment['CommentID'].'" class="submit" value="submit"/>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure, the .submit button type should not be submit. If you trigger manually, then the button type should not be submit. It should be button.

Comment: obvious your First Form will be submit because you are using Class name of submit button and  then trigger in Js so this will findout class name in page and first form will be find then it will submit that. you can use Form Id instead of Submit button's Class name.

Comment: dear it is not possible at time one single form will be submited

Comment: You can submit multiple forms at a single time instead you can get data of other form and send it in a single form submission request using ajax, its one solution

Comment: @Alex, I cannot use form Id since they are all dynamically created.
I have tried to use .closest and .find too but those need to be as the onClick attribute in the button.

Comment: I was thinking of using queryselectorAll as another option. Could that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong quote used here

```
$output .='<textarea name="edit_text" class="box" rows="2" cols="1">'.$this->getCommentText($comment['Comment_Text']).'</textarea>';
```

Comment: In addition to this correct answer, seems to be an empty `data-` attribute. That's invalid since is ended with an hypen.

Comment: **UPDATE** 
I have changed the name of the trigger in JS to 'input[type="button"]'. Now this seemed to work, because it printed the data-id values that were being submitted on click. But it still takes the text from the first comment. I have tried using data-id for the text area as well, but it still alerts the first comment box that was loaded.